# SUPEE 6788 INSTALL or WAIT?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

Recently released Magento Patch SUPEE 6788, should I install it or wait ?

I tried installing it on test website but it's really causing pretty much breaks all extensions.

So the question is whether it's best to wait or instal current patch despite all the issues it causing on front and backend.

Comment: "I want to shoot myself in the head. Should I wait for the fake bullets to arrive, or just keep using real bullets?"

Comment: My biggest issues after patch were caused by not having my Blocks on the new white list. You can add them under System > Permission > Blocks. Also, don't forget to flush cache ;p

Comment: Install it on your development server and test it. Find out where the failures are, contact your 3rd party module developers for upgrades and figure out where your templates are breaking and add the items to the whitelist. Waiting till your customers get ShopLifted is a plan for business failure. You don't install it despite the issues, you fix the issues on the test server so you can install it.

Answer (score 3):

Not installing it is gambling with your site's security, your business, and (probably most importantly) your customer's personal information.

If you don't want to install it and fix it now then I'd suggest you put your site into maintanence mode (or otherwise offline it) until it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox Its a tool which helps a great deal with this update. The actual answer to your question, is, if Magento tell you to update immediately then do it. They know better than anyone what the risks are.

Answer (score 0):

Patch resolves many security holes from magento setup so one must install security patch on production site to avoid potential future security attacks.

In regards of your que Install or Wait,

Patch should be applied as soon as possible but one can wait for next few days(may be this week) until installed external extension compatible release is not available. Almost all extension provider are working to release compatible version so should be available in couple of days.

that way site will be safe as well as not being harmed due to unavailability of external extension.

In case, any extension doesn't provide compatible release within this week, try with magento develper & get external extension modification by following patch [document guideline](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Note : Prefer to install on development/beta copy first